# Phone to Wear message (via message api) not received

Tags: android, wear-os

I've been trying to send messages via the message API from my phone to my androidWear. It's not working so far and I'm running out of idea about why.

I've got a simple app on the phone sending messages, here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";
private static final String WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH = "/message";

private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
    initGoogleApiClient();
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi( Wearable.API )
            .build();

    mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mApiClient.disconnect();
}

private void init() {
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list_view );
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.input );
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn_send );

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                mAdapter.add(text);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, text);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage( final String path, final String text ) {
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PutDataMapRequest pdmr = PutDataMapRequest.create(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH);
            pdmr.getDataMap().putString("message", text);
            PutDataRequest dataRequest = pdmr.asPutDataRequest();
            dataRequest.setUrgent();
            PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> result = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mApiClient, dataRequest);

            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                    if(dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                        Log.v("MESSAGE APP", "MESSAGE SENT");
                    }
                }
            });

            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mEditText.setText( "" );
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    sendMessage(START_ACTIVITY, "");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
}
```

When I click the send button, it sends the message, when I debug it I can see it finds my wear (Node) and sends the message (callback returns success).

But the wear receives nothing : 
Activity Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
implements MessageApi.MessageListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

private static final String WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH = "/message";
private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, R.layout.list_item );
    mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    initGoogleApiClient();
}

private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
            .addApi( Wearable.API )
            .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
            .build();

    if( mApiClient != null && !( mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting() ) )
        mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if( mApiClient != null && !( mApiClient.isConnected() || mApiClient.isConnecting() ) )
        mApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.v("WEAR MESSAGE", "Data changed");

    for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // DataItem changed
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
            if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH) == 0) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
                final String msg = dataMap.getString("message");
                runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.add(msg);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
            // DataItem deleted
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Wearable.DataApi.addListener( mApiClient, this );
    startService(new Intent(this, WearMessageListenerService.class));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if ( mApiClient != null ) {
        Wearable.DataApi.removeListener( mApiClient, this );
        if ( mApiClient.isConnected() ) {
            mApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if( mApiClient != null )
        mApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks( this );
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.d("MESSAGE APP", "Connection suspended");
}
}
```

And the manifest (I guess the problem comes from here) :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I've tried with path="/message" and it doesn't work either.

Any idea how to make that work

**UPDATE :**
After seeing that a succesfull response using the message API doesn't mean the message actually reaches the wear I changed everyhing to use the DataApi. (I changed the code above accordingly).

Still nothing on the wear .... but I tried something, I put a DataApi listener on my phone activity and it sees the change (if that helps figuring out what's wrong). So the phone activity sees the DataCHange but not the wear ...
That makes me think that I actually didn't set up my hardware correctly.

Comment: 1. Remove `pathPattern` 2. You don't need to start your service yourself, the lifecycle is managed by Android Wear

Comment: Yes I added this line for a test sorry, it's not there in my code. Removing the pathPattern doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it : both apps (wear and phone) must have the same ApplicationId (packageName).
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a design issue here. You are trying to start an Activity in response to a data layer event, and then respond to this event within this activity. This isn't really how the data APIs are designed to be used.

You have a few choices.

1. You have an Activity already running that receives and handles the data layer events via `Wearable.DataApi.addListener`, `Wearable.MessageApi.addListener`, etc.
2. You don't have an Activity already running, and you receive your data events or messages through your own [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService), and you start a new activity from this service. This service will be started for you by the system whenever there is an interesting "wearable" event (such as data, message or node change). You must remember to include appropriate manifest entries to make your service wake in response to each type of event -- check out the "Example manifest entry" section in the documentation I linked above for some more clarity.

See the `WearableListenerService` documentation. Essentially, you should just override `onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer)` or `onMessageReceived(MessageEvent)` depending on whether you want to handle a data event or a message event, and then start your activity from your service (i.e. with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`)

Hope this helps

Comment: The code about starting an activity was a test, I actually have a WearableListenerService that listens to this event and start the activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. I Have an activity running that should receive the messages I send, but doesn't. Could it be a problem with the version of software running on the wear ?

Comment: I suppose if you have vastly different play services versions on both devices, you might have an issue, since play services is what facilitates this kind of IPC. I find that unlikely when working with recent, production devices -- if you look in logcat for gms output, you should see warnings about such incompatibility if that's the case. It would be helpful to see your WearableListenerService implementation and how you're forwarding messages to your activity.